# Headless Chrome on Windows does not work with `repl`

Tags: windows, google-chrome, headless

On CentOS I can make `--repl` work however on Windows I cant. On my latest Windows I opened "cmd" with admin rights and executed:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --headless=new --repl`

As soon as I execute this command, it does nothing (the `cmd` should hang and allow me to type JS commands but the terminal simply goes to the next line). See print attached.

Any idea how I can fix this?

[image]